# Initializers in array, but I wanna control each object in array with variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I have an array with objects, like this:

```
var animals = [new Animal("dog", "Max"), new Animal("dog", "Ben"), new Animal("cat", "Ella"), new Animal("cat", "Sophia")];
```

And now I need to control each object as variable, like this:

```
console.log(dog_max.sound());
console.log(cat_sophia.eat());
```

How should I do it?

Theoretically, I don't know which object is what index,

I'll use random mix function for array.

Comment: In simple words you are asking for dynamic variable names.

Comment: describe Animal (class)

Comment: make a resolve method / class. E.g. `AnimalFinder.GetDogMax(Animal[])`

Comment: why do you need this anyway?

Comment: You must have some input parameter. Like *"In this array, find a `dog` which is named `Max`"*. This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Please post your inputs and the expected output and a clear problem statement.

Comment: You should not just create an arbitrary data structure, and then wrestle with it when you need some data from it. Rather plan the data structure according to the needs you have, think how you're going to use the structure, and buid it so that it's easy to find data in the different use cases. If you're handling some external data you can't control, the first step is to convert the data structure to suit to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create dynamic variable names which is not possible with `eval()`

### Using `eval()`

```js
class Animal{
  constructor(name1,name2){
    this.name1 = name1
    this.name2 = name2
  }
  sound(){
    return `${this.name1} makes sound`;
  }
}
var animals = [new Animal("dog", "Max"), new Animal("dog", "Ben"), new Animal("cat", "Ella"), new Animal("cat", "Sophia")];


for(let i = 0;i<animals.length;i++){
  eval(`var ${animals[i].name1}_${animals[i].name2.toLowerCase()} = animals[i]`);
}

console.log(dog_max.sound())
console.log(cat_ella.sound())
```

### Using `Object`

But using `eval()` is not recommended. You can can create a object to store these

```js
class Animal{
  constructor(name1,name2){
    this.name1 = name1
    this.name2 = name2
  }
  sound(){
    return `${this.name1} makes sound`;
  }
}
var animals = [new Animal("dog", "Max"), new Animal("dog", "Ben"), new Animal("cat", "Ella"), new Animal("cat", "Sophia")];

let a = {};
for(let i = 0;i<animals.length;i++){
  a[`${animals[i].name1}_${animals[i].name2.toLowerCase()}`] = animals[i]
}

console.log(a.dog_max.sound())
console.log(a.cat_ella.sound())
```